# improper setting variable in objectiveC

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I'm facing issue that xcode showing me warning: `Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'id _Nullable' to parameter of type 'unsigned long long'`

the line is:

`NSDecimalNumber *amount_total = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:indic[@"amount"] exponent:-2 isNegative:NO];`

it complain of `indic[@"amount"]` and this is a value of amount came from React-Native. even if I console log this in xcode it showing me a number which is came right from RN.

any solution to avoid that, however the app also crash because of this.

Thanks

Comment: `indic[@"amount"]` is what? a `NSNumber` I presume? Could it be that you need to replace it to `[indic[@"amount"] integerValue]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foundation collections (including `NSDictionary`) store numbers as `NSNumber` objects. The error is informing you that it is expecting an unsigned long long, so you should use `unsignedLongLongValue` to extract that value from the `NSNumber` in your `NSDictionary`:

```objectivec
NSDecimalNumber *amount_total = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:[indic[@"amount"] unsignedLongLongValue] exponent:-2 isNegative:NO];
```

See [Most Collections Are Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH7-SW11) and [Numbers Are Represented by Instances of the NSNumber Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH7-SW7).

Comment: That's works, Thanks